# How to get a value from html element in Android?

Tags: android, html-parsing

How can I get only "H4sIAAA"?

```
String out='<input type="hidden" name="javax.faces.ViewState" id="javax.faces.ViewState" value="H4sIAAA"  autocomplete="off" />';
```

Answer (score -1):

```
final String VALUE = "value=\"";
int start = out.indexOf(VALUE) + VALUE.length();
int end = out.indexOf("\"", start);
System.out.println(out.substring(start, end));
```

Answer (score -1):

The best way to do stuff like this is to use regular expressions.

A simple example matching exactly your problem:

```
String out= "<input type=\"hidden\" name=\"javax.faces.ViewState\" id=\"javax.faces.ViewState\" value=\"H4sIAAA\"  autocomplete=\"off\" />";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(".*(value=\"(\\w*)\").*", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(out);

if (matcher.matches()) {
  System.out.println(matcher.group(2));
}
```

This is working only for one line inputs with one accourance of a "value=".

What does it do?

1. It prepares a regular expression matcher which matches the whole string, a group with the "value" attribute and a second group with the value of the attribute "value"
2. It creates a matcher using the pattern and your given string "out"
3. If the matcher matches it prints out group content 2, which is the attributes value

The benefit of using regular expression is that you can make your expression ignoring all useless content regardless what it is and concentrat on your extract you want.
This example is only usefull for one line input with exactly one value attribute. When you want to parse hole html pages, you have to extend it to your needs.

Regex doc: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/package-summary.html
Good place to test regex: http://regexr.com/

Have fun!